# Compute multiple cycles in directed graph using scipy.csgraph

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

## Single cycle (works)

Consider the following directed graph:

```
>>> g
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This graph contains the cycle `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0`. Using [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html) I can find out the distances between nodes:

```
>>> d = csgraph.shortest_path(g)
>>> d
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2., inf, inf],
       [ 2.,  0.,  1., inf, inf],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0., inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf,  0.,  1.],
       [inf, inf, inf, inf,  0.]])
```

I can then detect cycles in that graph by checking if for any connection `i -> j (i != j)` there exists the opposite connection `j -> i`:

```
>>> d + d.T
array([[ 0.,  3.,  3., inf, inf],
       [ 3.,  0.,  3., inf, inf],
       [ 3.,  3.,  0., inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf,  0., inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, inf,  0.]])
```

For a single cycle I can obtain the corresponding nodes by checking the "edge-head" indexes of the corresponding connections:

```
>>> np.unique(np.argwhere(
...     (cycles > 0)
...     & (cycles != np.inf)
... )[:, 0])
array([0, 1, 2])
```

## Multiple cycles (the question)

But what if the graph contains multiple cycles (possibly of the same length) as for example:

```
>>> g
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

which contains the cycles `0 -> 1 -> 0` and `2 -> 3 -> 2`. Using the above method I cannot distinguish between the two different cycles.

I have a feeling that the option [`csgraph.shortest_path(..., return_predecessors=True)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html) together with [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.reconstruct_path`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.reconstruct_path.html) could be helpful, but I still don't see a way of differentiating between the two cycles and also `csgraph.reconstruct_path` expects a predecessors list while `csgraph.shortest_path` returns a corresponding matrix.

So is there a way to obtain all cycles from a graph by using the functions provided by `scipy.csgraph`?

Comment: What do you consider a cycle? Would `[[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]` be considered being one or two (or maybe three) cycles?

Comment: @JohanL [A cycle is a path of edges and vertices wherein a vertex is reachable from itself.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) In the sense of a *simple cycle* no repetitions are allowed and therefore your example would be considered two distinct cycles (`0 -> 1 -> 0` and `0 -> 2 -> 0`).